# Which gas among radon and hydrogen chloride has higher ideal behavior?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, gas-laws

> Which one among the following shows maximum ideal behaviour?
>
> 1. $\ce{NH3}$
> 2. $\ce{HCl}$
> 3. $\ce{Rn}$
> 4. $\ce{H2O}$

Ammonia and water have hydrogen bonding so they're ruled out. That leaves radon and $\ce{HCl}$. Radon is a noble gas which means inertness **but** it's too big in size. That could mean greater van der Waal forces. And $\ce{HCl}$ on the other hand has covalent bonding.

I want to confirm which one of them is more ideal.

Answer (score 3):

Some molecules are highly polar and thus are subject to electrostatic (dipole-dipole) interactions, which are typically far stronger than the interactions of induced dipoles (commonly referred to as van der Waals forces). See where this gets you.